# Where are iptables rules stored on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I have a basic standard Ubuntu 14.04 droplet on digital ocean. I used ufw to set some firewall rules but forgot to open port 22 for SSH. I rebooted my server and could no longer log in so DO support booted me into recovery mode so I can fix this up.

Unfortunately I have no idea where the iptables or ufw config files are saved. I've googled for ages and tried all these locations and none exist:

- /etc/iptables
- /etc/ufw
- /etc/sysconfig
- /lib/ufw
- /var/lib/iptables

Where could they possibly be?

Answer (score 2):

Ah found them at /lib/ufw/user.rules. But it's actually mounted as /mnt/lib/ufw/user.rules in recovery mode.

Comment: I have a MEAN Stack running on Ubuntu 14.04.  I found them in `/usr/share/ufw/iptables/{after,before,user}{,6}.rules`.